# Allocate multi-dimensional array in D at runtime

Tags: memory-management, multidimensional-array, d

Is it possible to allocate 2-dimensional arrays (and higher) in D?

The following does not work:

```
void create2DArray(uint w, uint h) {
    double[][] histogram = new double[w][h];
}
```

however, the following compiles fine:

```
void create1DArray(uint w) {
    double[] histogram = new double[w];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use constructor syntax like this:

```
void create2DArray(uint w, uint h) {
    double[][] histogram = new double[][](w, h);
}
```

That works fine, at least in D2.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposal http://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/~nn245/documents/D-multidimarray.html

Looks like you have to allocate each row for itself with a loop.